# Priority for "always on top" X windows

Tags: xorg, x11, xfce, window-manager

I have two windows on my Xfce desktop that need to be open all the time and they are set to *always on top*. They overlap each other, whenever I click on one of them, that's expected behaviour.

Is possible somehow to give one of them a certain priority, so both of them stay always on top, but window 1 stays always over window 2?

Comment: Does it work if you set them to _always on top_ sequentially? I mean is the one you set second always above the one you set first? Or is it random?

Comment: @terdon Yes, but when I click on one of them, it gets raised. I updated the question!

Comment: I don't know if you can prioritize the windows, but you should be able to check if Window 1 is on the top of the stack and raise it. I don't think such a check is that costly (CPU wise) and could be done every 1-3 seconds, depending on the (for you) acceptable delay.

Comment: @Anthon the other day I wrote a script with *wmctrl* that would raise the window every *N* seconds, and from what I can remember, there was some problem like the focus being stolen from text editors, or something like that. I'll try it again.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior That might be the case, I haven't tried to do this, it would be the thing I would try. I haven't noticed `wmctrl` taking influencing the focus, but that might depend on the application.

Comment: @Anthon I have tried it again, and *stjerm*'s (a dropdown term) toggle key stops working until I give any window the focus manually.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior My next step would be to either see if you can change the source of `stjerm` to make it behave wrt to the focus (and maybe make it auto-raising), or alternatively look at `xdotool` to simulate clicking on it to get/keep the `stjerm` in the state you want. The former is cleaner, the second probably more easy to try

Comment: @Anthon it works, but then the focus is constantly stolen from the current window.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Do you mean the `xdotool` approach? If so try and execute it only when the window is not on top.

Comment: @Anthon I can only figure how to detect if the windows is focused, and it will not be focused most of the time.